# Why is item.getMenuInfo() null?

Tags: android, menuitem

Within my ListVeiw item I have 4-8 ImageView(some of them are invisible depended of some value) and 4 TextView.

When I Long click to item of Listview the (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo() returns me null.

In my adapter I have defined the following methods:

```
public int getCount() {
   return NewList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
   return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
}

public void Remove(int id){
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

   View vi=convertView;
   NewsFeedHolder holder;
   News n= NewList.get(position);
   List<NewsItem> items = n.getNewsItems();
   int ItemsLen = items.size();

   if (convertView == null){

       vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_item, null);

       holder=new NewsFeedHolder();

       holder.txtTitle        = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_item_name);
       holder.avatar_image    = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_item_icon);
       holder.txtUpdate       = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_item_update);
       holder.txtLike         = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_item_like); 
       holder.txtDisLike      = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_item_dislike);
       holder.btnLike         = (ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_like_button) ;
       holder.btntxtDisLike   = (ImageButton)vi.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_dislike_button); 

       holder.imgItemIcon1    = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_item_icon1);
       holder.imgItemIcon2    = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_item_icon2);
       holder.imgItemIcon3    = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.newsfeed_item_icon3);
       holder.btnLike.setOnClickListener(activity.OnLikeClickListener);
       holder.btntxtDisLike.setOnClickListener(activity.OnDisLikeOnClickListener);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    } 
    else {
          holder=(NewsFeedHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

   imageLoader.DisplayImage(n.getUserAvatarUrl(), activity, holder.avatar_image);
   String url1,url2,url3;

    try{

        switch(ItemsLen){


        case 1:
            url1 = n.getNewsItems().get(0).getItemUrl();
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(url1, activity, holder.imgItemIcon1);  
            break;

        case 2:
            url1 = n.getNewsItems().get(1).getItemUrl();
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(url1, activity, holder.imgItemIcon1);  
            url2 = n.getNewsItems().get(1).getItemUrl();
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(url2, activity, holder.imgItemIcon2);
            break;

        case 3:
            url1 = n.getNewsItems().get(2).getItemUrl();
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(url1, activity, holder.imgItemIcon1);  
            url2 = n.getNewsItems().get(2).getItemUrl();
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(url2, activity, holder.imgItemIcon2);
            url3 = n.getNewsItems().get(2).getItemUrl();
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(url3, activity, holder.imgItemIcon3);
            break;

    default:

    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("adaptex",e.getMessage());
    }


    holder.txtTitle.setText(n.getNewsTitle());
    holder.txtUpdate.setText(n.getUpdate());
    holder.txtLike.setText(Integer.toString(n.getLike()));
    holder.txtDisLike.setText(Integer.toString(n.getDesLike()));

    activity.registerForContextMenu(vi);

    vi.setOnClickListener(activity.OnListItemClickListener);


    return vi;

}
```

And when I attempt to get `item.getMenuInfo()`, I receive null.

Answer (score 3):

You need to register the list for context menu, not the items.

```
// wrong:
activity.registerForContextMenu(vi);

// right:
activity.registerForContextMenu(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not have anything to do with it, but one glaring thing I see right away is:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
   return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

Your getItem method is returning an `int` of the object's position, not the actual `Object` itself as stated in its method declaration.

Comment: Unfortunately,I have tried public Object getItem(int position) {
    News obj = NewList.get(position);
       return obj;
   },but this doesn't get me any result

Answer (score 0):

getMenuInfo() will work on ListAdapter, not on views.

But, You can pass additional data with the tag of the view.

in getView:
vi.setTag(position)
activity.registerForContextMenu(vi);

declare in Activity
private int id;

onCreateContextMenu:
id = (int) v.getTag();

onContextItemSelected:
you can use the id

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago. After taking a deep look at the documentation, I found out one has to pass the data of the selected item to the ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo object in the root view of the item in adapter inside the view's View.OnCreateContextMenuListener using the View#setOnCreateContextMenuListener method. However, there are no methods to do this and setting the object using an AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo constructor does not actually overwrite it's null value. Thus I used a custom object to pass these values in the View#setOnCreateContextMenuListener method and get the values in the AppCompatActivity#onContextItemSelected method. Here's how my codes were...

This was my item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?recyclerItemBackground">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/name_tv"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="anville"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/number_tv"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="anville"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this was my adapter, I set the View#setOnCreateContextMenuListener in the RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder method

```
package io.github.anville95work.menuexample;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<People> peopleList;
    private PositionHolder positionHolder;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<People> peopleList, PositionHolder  positionHolder) {
        this.context = context;
        this.peopleList = peopleList;
        this.positionHolder = positionHolder;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.getNameTV().setText(peopleList.get(position).getName());
        holder.getPhoneTV().setText(String.valueOf(peopleList.get(position).getNumber()));
        //MUST SET CREATE CONTEXT MENU LISTENER
        holder.getItemView().setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                positionHolder.setPosition(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return peopleList.size();
    }
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setLongClickable(true);
        //YOU MUST SET_LONG_CLICKABLE TO TRUE FOR CONTEXT MENU TO WORK
    }

    private TextView nameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
    private TextView phoneTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_tv);

    public TextView getNameTV() {
        return nameTV;
    }

    public TextView getPhoneTV() {
        return phoneTV;
    }

    public View getItemView() {
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

And Here's my AppCompatActivity, I created a private object of PositionHolder and passed a reference to the adapter object for modification upon context menu creation. I added the PositionHolder class at the bottom.

```
package io.github.anville95work.menuexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PositionHolder positionHolder = new PositionHolder(0);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        ArrayList<People> peopleArrayList = new ArrayList<People>();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 40; i++) {
            peopleArrayList.add(new People("anville-" + i, 2547 + i));
        }

        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, peopleArrayList, positionHolder);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //CONTEXT MENU
        //YOU MUST SET_LONG_CLICKABLE TO TRUE IN VIEW_HOLDER FOR CONTEXT MENU TO WORK
        registerForContextMenu(recyclerView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.option1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You selected the first option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.option2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You selected the second option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.option3:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You selected the third option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.option4:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You selected the fourth option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.option5:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You selected the fifth option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, "How did this come to be?!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //USE THIS METHOD TO MODIFY THE MENU IN RUN_TIME IF NEED BE.
        //to update the menu you must call invalidateOptionsMenu() so as to trigger a callBack for this method
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        System.out.println("Position: " + String.valueOf(positionHolder.getPosition()));
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.context_option1:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You want option1 for " + positionHolder.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.context_option2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You want option2 for " + positionHolder.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.context_option3:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You want option3 for " + positionHolder.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.context_option4:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You want option4 for " + positionHolder.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.context_option5:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You want option5 for " + positionHolder.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(this, "I have no idea what you want for " + positionHolder.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}

class PositionHolder {
    private int position;

    public PositionHolder(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Everything worked well. Thank you for reading, happy coding.