# MenuIntem getMenuInfo() returns null when creating a context menu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to make sense of the android API guide for creating context menus but they really don't give any explanation on how AdapterContextMenuInfo is supposed to be used.

My code:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsAdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
...

public class MyActivity extends SherlockActivity {}
    ...
    class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        ...
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            registerForContextMenu(rowView);
            return rowView;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        Log.d(MyApp.LOG_TAG, "info is null: "+ (info == null)); // info is null: true
        ...
    }
}
```

From my vague understanding on how context menus are supposed to work I expected info to contain the db row id or at least the targetView from which I could retrieve the id as a tag.

Please let me know where I am going wrong or how else I can detect for which ListView item the context menu was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

[android - why item.getMenuInfo is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190451/why-item-getmenuinfo-is-null)

The asker didn't mark it as the accepted answer so I don't know if it solved his problem, but it looks like you're doing the same thing he did.

Register the menu as the context menu rather than the row items.

Comment: According to that answer I should call registerForContextMenu passing in my ListView which is backed by the CursorAdapter. However when I do, longpress actions are not registered at all even after unbinding all click listeners from the views in each row of the ListView.