# How do you pass an ImageView's ID to onContextItemSelected?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-tablelayout, android-contextmenu

I am registering a floating context menu to an ImageView in a TableLayout and opening the menu with setOnClickListener. I am wondering how to get the ImageView's id in onContextItemSelected. AdapterContextMenuInfo only returns null because, I'm assuming, ImageView doesn't use an Adapter. xnagyg's answer in this question, [why item.getMenuInfo() is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190451/why-item-getmenuinfo-is-null), in essence does what I want but what is the proper way of accessing the ImageView's id?

Comment: You can use setTag with a complete class for more data for a given row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the suggestion in the link you posted, or you can build a data structure to indicate which views = what id. You could use a hashmap of [view's id,position] (can't use carrots) and then update this every time a view is modified.

Comment: That makes sense. I think I will have to do something like what you suggested to keep track of everything. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some simple API solution I was missing. Thanks.